# Is there a way to link to a specific position inside a video on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

In order to make the video start on a specific minute and second?

I know [YouTube does it](https://youtu.be/YiWMP9S3uxQ?t=5m26s) and was hoping to find out if this can be done in Google Drive as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same method as YouTube, but it's a little more tricky to get the correct URL.

In Drive, find your video. Click on the shared link. It'll give you something like:

`https://drive.google.com/open?id=AbCd12345longKeyHere`

You need to change the format to:

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/AbCd12345longKeyHere/view`

Now, like with YouTube, you can tag on your time query right to the URL:

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/AbCd12345longKeyHere/view?t=1m25s`

The video will open to the correct time when someone clicks the link. Note that you need to make sure your sharing permissions allow someone to open the video.

Comment: Will this work for audio files? If not, is there a different (working) method for audio files?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for videos recorded with google meet :(

Comment: Just tried this now and doesn't work for me either (recording from Google Meet)

Comment: I just tested and it still works on Drive.