# Within a "Shared Drive" in Google Workspace, how can I share a video that starts at a specified time?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-drive-sharing, google-shared-drive

Within a "Shared Drive" in Google Workspace, how can I share a video that starts at a specified time? Solutions posted previously on this forum do not work.

I have uploaded a video to a Shared Drive folder in Google Drive. I link to that video in Google Doc in the same Shared Drive and I can't get the video to start at specific times.

I tried the recommendation from this post but it doesn't work.
[Is there a way to link to a specific position inside a video on Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99936/is-there-a-way-to-link-to-a-specific-position-inside-a-video-on-google-drive/149876)?
noredirect=1#comment136537_149876

This is the example https://drive.google.com/file/d/AbCd12345longKeyHere/view?t=1m25s and tried adding that "t=1m25s" to my video link and there is no error. It opens the video at the very beginning. No error, it just doesn't start that 1m25s timestamp.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Questions should be self-contained, please briefly describe what you tried and if you got an error message add it textually.